# PostgreSQL - added uuid column is null when foreign key is `on delete set null`

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using: `PostgreSQL 11.11 (Debian 11.11-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`

I have a table `customer` which is defined somewhat like:

```
create table "customer" ("id" serial, primary key ("id"));
```

and another table `queueCustomer` which is defined somewhat like:

```
create table "queueCustomer" (
  "id": serial,
  "customerId" integer references "customer"("id") on delete set null,
  primary key ("id")
);
```

I'm trying to write a migration that changes "customer"."id" to a UUID, updating the other tables referencing it.

So far what I have is:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

begin;
    alter table "customer" rename column "id" to "oldId";
    alter table "customer" add "id" uuid unique not null default uuid_generate_v4();

    -- Altering queueCustomer:
    alter table "queueCustomer" rename column "customerId" to "oldCustomerId";
    alter table "queueCustomer" add "customerId" uuid references "customer"("id");
    update "queueCustomer" set "customerId" = (select "id" from "customer" c where c."oldId" = "oldCustomerId");
    alter table "queueCustomer" drop column "oldCustomerId";

    alter table "customer" drop constraint customer_pkey;
    alter table "customer" add primary key (id);
    alter table "customer" drop column "oldId";
commit;
```

However, the `id` column ends up being full of `NULL`s.

Narrowing things down, doing just the beginning like so:

```
begin;
    alter table "customer" rename column "id" to "oldId";
    alter table "customer" add "id" uuid unique not null default uuid_generate_v4();
    select * from "customer";
rollback;
```

`"Customer"."id"` is `NULL`, even though I expect it to be an unique UUID in each row.

I can't just `update "customer" set "id"=uuid_generate_v4();` because since it's in a transaction, the `uuid_generate_v4()` procedure will always return the same value.

Comment: Can't reproduce in `psql`. The issue is likely with the GUI I use called DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create the same scenario,

Kindly check the below queries, it's creating UUID for each row.

```
create table test
(
id int
);

insert into test values(1);
insert into test values(2);
insert into test values(3);

alter table "test" rename column "id" to "oldId";
alter table "test" add "id" uuid unique not null default uuid_generate_v4();
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/16a18/1

Comment: Your query works on your table. Maybe something is odd about how my `customer` table is defined?

Comment: please also mention your Postgres version, on SQL fiddle, I tried on Postgres 9.6

Comment: I edited the question to include the postgres version: `PostgreSQL 11.11 (Debian 11.11-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`

Comment: What can I check to troubleshoot the difference between my existing table and your table?

Comment: I narrowed down my issue and updated the question.